# RouterLink Not Appearing Properly in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, element-ui

I have a problem using the routerLink in Vue Js. It only shows the localhost:8080/#/purchase-orders. It should be localhost:8080/#/purchase-orders/2 since i added the params property. How should i fix this?

```
<el-table-column
                            fixed="right"
                            property="action"
                            label="Action"
                            width="120">
                            <template slot-scope="scope">
                                <router-link :to="{ path: '', params: { id: 2 }}">
                                    <el-button type="text" size="small">Detail</el-button>
                                </router-link>
                                <el-button type="text" size="small">Edit</el-button>
                            </template>
                        </el-table-column>
```

Answer (score 2):

**params** are ignored if **path** is used.
You need to use **name** instead.

It should like this: (assuming **orders** is the name of route)

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'orders', params: { id: 2 }}">
```

Alternatively, if you wanna use **path**, you have to provide full path.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

> Note: params are ignored if a path is provided, which is not the case for query, as shown in the example above. Instead, you need to provide the name of the route or manually specify the whole path with any parameter:

Comment: Can you provide me your definition of routes? (Usually router.js)

Comment: The routes are working. When i type something in the url its navigating. The problem is on that button only